# Configure NServiceBus Retries to not bother on ApplicationException

Tags: nservicebus

I understand NServiceBus's retry mechanism to be primarily for connectivity problems or database deadlock problems, which is great and I love it for that.

However, I would like to configure NServiceBus' retry mechanism to not bother with a retry if the exception is typeof(ApplicationException).  My code throws this kind of exception when there is a broken business rule (like a customer on hold), so no matter how many times this message is retried by NServiceBus' quick-retry mechanism, it will fail.  This scenario requires that users take action on the data and then use ServiceInsight to re-queue the message for processing.

Can this be done?

Comment: Couldn't there be a situation where another message comes along during the retry window and changes the state of your business data (making the customer no longer on-hold)?

Comment: The chances of this are very slim, considering that this first-level retry window would be less than a minute.  If it does happen, it certainly would be co-incidental, and not due to a user removing the customer on-hold state in order to make the saga flow through without exceptions.

Comment: Couldn't the client check whether a customer is on hold before sending that message though?

Answer (score 3):

I would reconsider using your application logic to inform users about this type of errors using Reply or Return in your handler, that should be located in the catch (ApplicationException) section. Then users change the data and send the message again using your application, not ServiceInsight. In this case, do not re-throw the ApplicationException in your catch block and this will prevent NServiceBus from retrying your message handling.

Comment: I disagree.  I think ServiceInsight's Retry feature is perfect for what I need.  I essentially have only one "end user", and that is the system administrator who just monitors ServiceInsight, and instructs various persons in the organisation to take the necessary corrective action.  Your suggestion means I write my own retry logic and user interface when this is already available in ServiceInsight.

Comment: It will work only until your administrator is able to monitor the system. In case he gets ill, goes on holidays, number of errors increase due to the system load, the solution will stop working.